# CSS Holy Grail (liquid main, fixed right), added DIVs not extending with small amount of content?

Tags: css

I am using A List Apart's "Holy Grail" for a liquid main column with a fixed right column (their column shows a left column also, but I've eliminated it). I have added DIVs within the main column area and right column area and these additional DIVs have borders (which also helps us to see the dimensions of the DIV).

When my DIV in the main column has a large amount of content, it forces the DIV to extend to a point 10 px before the right column (which is how I would like it to behave).

When my DIV in the main column has a small amount of content, the DIV wraps around the content and does not extend to a point 10 px before the right column. I would like it to extend. I have tried adding width:100%, but this results in an overextension of the DIV. I would like to avoid using things like 99%, etc. Any ideas as to how I can accomplish this? My HTML and CSS is below.

```
    <html><head>
    <style>
    body {min-width: 400px;         /* 2 x RC fullwidth */}
    #container {padding-right: 177px;     /* RC fullwidth + CC padding */}
    #container .column { /* position: relative; */ float: left;}
    #container .maintry1 { /* position: relative; float: left; */ padding:10px; border: 1px solid #cbcbcb; background-color:#fff;}
    #container .maintry2 { /* width:100%; position: relative; float: left; */ padding:10px; border: 1px solid #cbcbcb; background-color:#fff;}
    #container .rightnav { /* position: relative; float: left; */ padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px; border: 1px solid #cbcbcb; background-color:#fff;}
    #center { padding: 10px 10px; /* CC padding */ width: 100%;}
    #right {width: 147px;             /* RC width */
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 0px;          /* RC padding */
        margin-right: -100%;
    }
    #footer {clear: both;}
    /*** IE Fix ***/
    * html #left {left: 150px;              /* RC fullwidth */}
    /*** Just for Looks ***/
    body {margin: 0; padding: 0; font: 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background-color: #f6f6f6; color: #000; margin:0; padding:0;}
    #center {background-color: #f6f6f6;}
    #right {background-color: #f6f6f6;}
    #container .column {background-color: #f6f6f6;}

    #Group1 { display:inline-block; width:33%; background-color:#ff0000;}
    #Group2 { display:inline-block; width:33%; background-color:#00ff00;}
    #Group3 { display:inline-block; width:33%; background-color:#0000ff;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="center" class="column">
            <div class="maintry1">
            <p>#1. This DIV has a large amount of content and forces the DIV to encompass the intended area.<br>
            test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test </p>

            <div id="Group1">
                <ul>
                <li>test</li><li>test</li><li>test</li><li>test</li><li>test</li><li>test</li><li>test</li><li>test</li><li>test</li><li>test</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="Group2">
                <ul><li>test</li></ul>
            </div>
            <div id="Group3">
            <ul><li>test</li></ul>
            </div>

            </div>      
            <br>
            <div class="maintry1">
            <p>#2. This DIV has a small amount of content.<br> The DIV does not extend to the end of the intended area like the 1st DIV.<br> How can I get this DIV to go expand to the right with the intended 10px padding?</p>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="maintry2">
            <p>#3. This is the same as #2, but it has width:100% and it extends too far.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="right" class="column">
            <div class="rightnav">
            <p>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**UPDATE:** Here are the 2 snapshots related to my comments on 12/12/2011:

Old:
[image]

My Fix?
[image]

**UPDATE 12/13/2011**

Hi Purr,

Thank you very much for the follow-up. The code is helpful. Also, the box model is helpful to my understanding. For example, I would like to turn off the colors, and turn on a border-left on some of the DIVs, and this seems to break the rule of adding to 100%. When there are the group DIVs and I set each to 33.33%, and then I have two of the DIVs with a border of 1px (99.99% + 2 pixels), this also appears to surpass 100%. When I set to 33%, it seems to be okay for now based on my screen size, but this doesn't seem very scientific. Is there a preferred way of squeezing my borders in there? I will be making different iterations of this for 3, 5, 8 and 12 columns (possibly more), so the borders will start to add up and may have an impact.  I would like the wrapper to stay as close to 100% as possible. I've updated the Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zenfiddle/yUPCC/2/

Also, perhaps this is appropriate for another question, but perhaps there is a quick fix that we can handle here. My updated Fiddle shows the borders as stopping where the DIV wraps. I would like the borders to span the height of the parent DIV. I realize there are many ways to approach this and this has been discussed by various authors/developers. Is there a quick and sound fix? Whatever approach I take, I will be recalculating it for the 3, 5, 8 and 12 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
#container .column {
    /*position: relative;*/
    float: left;
}
#container .maintry1 {
    /*position: relative;
    float: left;*/
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
    background-color: #fff;
}
#container .maintry2 {
    /*width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;*/
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
    background-color: #fff;
}
#container .rightnav {
    /*position: relative;
    float: left;*/
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

I commented out the css rules that you can delete and it should have the effect that you want to have.

When you set a float:left; to .column you don't have to float the divs inside it. Divs are displayed as display:block per default, so they automatically take a width of 100%.

See also here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Fwta6/3/

**Update** (13.12.2011)

I would do it the same way, by floating the 3 divs left, so that they are displayed in one line. I updated the code: http://jsfiddle.net/yUPCC/

Let's take it apart.

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

I deleted the min-width of the body. When `#Groups` has a min-width and `.rightnav` a fixed width, it makes no sense to set a min-width to the `body` that is even smaller than the one from `#Groups`

```
body {
    font:14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color:#f6f6f6;
    color:#000;
}

.column {
    float:left;
    background-color:#f6f6f6;
    padding: 10px;
}

.rightnav {
    border:1px solid #cbcbcb;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

#center {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#f6f6f6;
    padding:10px; 
}

#right {
    width:147px;
    margin-right:-100%;
    background-color:#f6f6f6;
    padding:10px; 
}
```

I often use `overflow:hidden` instead of `float:none` or `clear:both`. You have to add it to the element that contains the floating element. By this, you are also avoiding the "under-/overflow" that you mentioned. It's the same that MiG explained in the other answer to this question.

```
#Groups {
    overflow:hidden;
    min-width:600px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Instead of adding `float:left`to every single div in `#Groups` you can address them by the following.

```
#Groups div {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
```

If you set a padding to the colored divs in `#Groups`, they will not display inline, because of the box model (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp). It would simply calculate 33% + 10px, which is more than 100% if multiplied by 3. That's why you can set a margin to the child element (in this case the ul) to get a "padding".

```
#Groups ul {margin: 10px; }
#Group1 { background-color:red; }
#Group2 { background-color:#0f0; }
#Group3 { background-color:#00f; }
```

I deleted the `<br />` between the divs and instead set a `margin-bottom` to the divs.

```
.maintry1,
.maintry2 {
    border:1px solid #cbcbcb;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

I hope this is how you want it to be. I don't know if this is best practice css, but it works and that's what we want.

Comment: Purr: This worked great. I have a related follow-up question. I have a need to add more DIVs within the DIV as shown above (I've updated the code with your suggestions along with my extra DIVs (Group1, Group2 and Group3). For some reason these 3 groups are aligning to bottom, or really, there is some kind of steppage issue. This is evident when 1 group has more content (e.g. Group1 has more content than Group2 and Group3). How can I adjust these 3 groups?

Comment: Which browser do you use? Do you work on a Windows PC or a Mac? I don't really get what you want to achieve. Maybe your browser displays  it differently than mine.

Comment: Hi Purr: Attached are 2 images. The first is a screenshot of the problem. The second is what I came up with to solve it. What I did was I added wrapper "#Groups" and then I floated the 3 groups to the left. I don't know if this conflicts with the strategy that we used elsewhere in the CSS code. Do you think it's a valid solution? Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Also, when I resize the the Result screen in JS Fiddle to make the Result screen smaller (clicking and dragging seaparator), my 3 Group DIVs end up being not so liquid and there is an overflow/underflow. Any idea on how I can make my 3 Group DIVs more liquid and reisizable?

#Groups { float:none; display:inline-block; min-width:600px; width:100%; }
#Group1 { float:left; width:33%; background-color:#ff0000; }
#Group2 { float:left; width:33%; background-color:#00ff00; }
#Group3 { float:left; width:33%; background-color:#0000ff; }

Comment: Also, I've posted the old and new code on JSFiddle:

Old (with problem):
http://jsfiddle.net/zenfiddle/97CDM/

New (fix, but still not liquid DIVs)
http://jsfiddle.net/zenfiddle/tYP2k/

Comment: PS. I've been using Windows and also testing on a Mac. Problem was occurring on both before my fix.

Answer (score 0):

> **I am using A List Apart's "Holy Grail" for a liquid main column with a fixed right column**

This is much simpler than the code you provided, even supporting IE6! You can reduce the the mark-up to this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="right">Test</div>
   <div class="left">Test</div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.container {
   overflow:hidden;
}
.left {
   margin-right:250px; 
   /* The width of the right column + margin + border, e.g. computed box size */
}
.right {
   float:right;
   width:250px;
   border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KHerm/

This works due to `.left` not really considering `.right` due to the `float` of `.right`. You can expand this to three columns but any more columns and you need to `float` them all. `overflow` is used as a `clearfix` on `container`.